# InstallAnywhere can't delete file if .Net program subscribed to Event Log notifications

Tags: windows, event-log, installanywhere

On Windows 7 Professional I've got a .Net program monitoring Windows Event Log.

On the same workstation is installed a Java program as a Windows service. This program needs to be uninstalled with InstallAnywhere. The uninstall ends with the Java service executable being held by my monitoring program (which I can clearly see using procexp.exe) even though it just manipulates the strings from the notification event - not ever trying to open neither the said process handle nor any other file.

I wonder whether this is a known behavior or a bug of Windows/.Net/InstallAnywhere.

If it is expected, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is expected Windows behaviour. The installer `jre` folder is locked for reading.
If the uninstallation finally ended, it is possible that the remaining folder (`jre`) or a file in that folder is flagged to be deleted after reboot. 
You can check if `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` contains that entry. 
If `true`, then it will be deleted after reboot.
Otherwise you will have to stop your monitoring program before attempting uninstallation.

Comment: I probably had to mention, that if my monitoring program is not running, or it is not connected to the Event log - the uninstall does delete the Java service executable. So it seems that Windows/.Net is holding on this Java executable handle in the context of my program even though we have nothing to do with it.